# Adding "LIMIT 1" to LATERAL JOIN causes Postgres 9.5.7 with mongo_fdw extension to crash

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, crash

I have the following *extremely simple* test case. It requires Postgresql 9.5.7, a Mongo database and uses the Mongo FDW Extension. It will fail using a table that has only one record. Here's how:

First, in the mongo shell, run the following command to create some data:

```
db.table2.insert({sessionKey:ObjectId('555233a2af8f312d060e57be'), catalog:'test'});
```

Then, run the below in PSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 AS SELECT column1 AS sid
    FROM (VALUES ('555233a2af8f312d060e57be'::name)) AS data;

CREATE EXTENSION mongo_fdw;
CREATE SERVER mongo_data FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER mongo_fdw OPTIONS (address 'localhost', port '27017');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres SERVER mongo_data;

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE table2 (
  "sessionKey" NAME,
  "catalog" TEXT
) SERVER mongo_data OPTIONS (DATABASE 'test', COLLECTION 'table2');
```

When you run the following query, the server will throw a segmentation fault.

```
SELECT t1.sid, t2.catalog
FROM table1 t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT catalog FROM table2 WHERE "sessionKey" = t1.sid LIMIT 1
  ) t2 ON TRUE;
```

However, if you run the query without the "LIMIT 1" it runs without a problem.

Looking at the execution plan, the only difference is the introduction of a filter expression.

```
# explain SELECT t1.sid, t2.catalog
FROM table1 t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
       SELECT catalog FROM table2 WHERE "sessionKey" = t1.sid        
       ) t2 ON TRUE;
                           QUERY PLAN                            
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=5.00..6.08 rows=1 width=96)
   Join Filter: (table2."sessionKey" = t1.sid)
   ->  Seq Scan on table1 t1  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=64)
   ->  Foreign Scan on table2  (cost=5.00..5.06 rows=1 width=96)
         Foreign Namespace: test.table2
(5 rows)

# explain SELECT t1.sid, t2.catalog
FROM table1 t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
       SELECT catalog FROM table2 WHERE "sessionKey" = t1.sid LIMIT 1
       ) t2 ON TRUE;
                              QUERY PLAN                               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=5.00..6.09 rows=1 width=96)
   ->  Seq Scan on table1 t1  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=64)
   ->  Limit  (cost=5.00..5.06 rows=1 width=32)
         ->  Foreign Scan on table2  (cost=5.00..5.06 rows=1 width=32)
               Filter: ("sessionKey" = t1.sid)
               Foreign Namespace: test.table2
(6 rows)
```

It appears that the evaluation of this filter expression is what causes the segmentation fault.

-- UPDATE 1 --

Running GDB, I received the following backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
106     ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
#1  0x000056452ce080db in MemoryContextStrdup ()
#2  0x000056452cdec0e7 in FunctionCall1Coll ()
#3  0x000056452cded6b7 in OutputFunctionCall ()
#4  0x000056452cded904 in OidOutputFunctionCall ()
#5  0x00007f056ee694f3 in AppenMongoValue 
    (queryDocument=queryDocument@entry=0x56452e217980, 
    keyName=keyName@entry=0x56452e242278 "sessionKey", value=0,
    isnull=<optimized out>, id=<optimized out>) at mongo_query.c:533
#6  0x00007f056ee69e02 in AppendParamValue (scanStateNode=0x56452e23abd8, 
    paramNode=<optimized out>, keyName=0x56452e242278 "sessionKey", 
    queryDocument=0x56452e217980)
    at mongo_query.c:410
#7  QueryDocument (relationId=relationId@entry=2207239, opExpressionList=
    <optimized out>, scanStateNode=scanStateNode@entry=0x56452e23abd8) at 
    mongo_query.c:218
#8  0x00007f056ee67f9f in MongoBeginForeignScan (scanState=0x56452e23abd8, 
    executorFlags=<optimized out>) at mongo_fdw.c:516
#9  0x000056452cc02315 in ExecInitForeignScan ()
#10 0x000056452cbe1a43 in ExecInitNode ()
#11 0x000056452cbf75bb in ExecInitLimit ()
#12 0x000056452cbe192d in ExecInitNode ()
#13 0x000056452cbfc537 in ExecInitNestLoop ()
#14 0x000056452cbe1a29 in ExecInitNode ()
#15 0x000056452cbdffba in standard_ExecutorStart ()
#16 0x000056452ccec1af in PortalStart ()
#17 0x000056452cce938d in PostgresMain ()
#18 0x000056452ca8305c in ?? ()
#19 0x000056452cc8d1b3 in PostmasterMain ()
#20 0x000056452ca84251 in main ()
```

Looking at the Mongo FDW code, I can see that the segfault is happening in mongo_query.c:

```
/* Prepare for parameter expression evaluation */
param_expr = ExecInitExpr((Expr *) paramNode, (PlanState *)scanStateNode);

/* Evaluate the parameter expression */
param_value = ExecEvalExpr(param_expr, econtext, &isNull, NULL);

AppenMongoValue(queryDocument, keyName, param_value, isNull,
            paramNode->paramtype);
```

I can paramNode->paramtype = 19 (NAMEOID), as expected. However, param_value = 0 (which is what is causing AppenMongoValue to crash). I'm not sure if this is a bug in the mongo_fdw extension or in Posgresql 9.5.7, but I need some help to find a way to work around this.

-- UPDATE 2 --

I dived into the PostgreSQL code (execQual.c, specifically) and I can see that there is no execution plan associated with the parameter "sessionKey".

```
static Datum
ExecEvalParamExec(ExprState *exprstate, ExprContext *econtext,
                  bool *isNull, ExprDoneCond *isDone)
{
    Param      *expression = (Param *) exprstate->expr;
    int         thisParamId = expression->paramid;
        ParamExecData *prm;

    if (isDone)
        *isDone = ExprSingleResult;

    /*
     * PARAM_EXEC params (internal executor parameters) are stored in the
     * ecxt_param_exec_vals array, and can be accessed by array index.
     */
    prm = &(econtext->ecxt_param_exec_vals[thisParamId]);
    if (prm->execPlan != NULL)
    {
    /* Parameter not evaluated yet, so go do it */
    ExecSetParamPlan(prm->execPlan, econtext);
    /* ExecSetParamPlan should have processed this param... */
    Assert(prm->execPlan == NULL);
    }
    *isNull = prm->isnull;
    return prm->value;
}
```

Because "prm->execPlan" is NULL, the value of the parameter is never set. I'm not sure that I can take this any further without help.

Comment: Backtrace? https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Linux/BSD . I suggest reporting a mongo_fdw bug.

Comment: I've provided quite a bit of additional information to the base post. Please take a look and tell me what you think.

Comment: I think you need to install the debuginfo for your postgres, those stack entries are function-only and don't have arguments etc. And really, you need to take this info to the mongo-fdw devs along with the (excellent) reproduction test case. I can't currently take the time to dig into it. They'll report it to pgsql-hackers if they determine it's a core bug.

Comment: Thanks, Craig. I posted it here (https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mongo_fdw/issues/82). Is this the right place?

Comment: Looks like it to me.